# Create MS Teams from existing SharePoint site url using pnp powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, microsoft-teams

Enable integration of Microsoft Teams to an existing SharePoint site rather than to always create a new site collection

There have been a few ideas raised on integrating lists, OneNote, document libraries, etc. from an existing SharePoint site with Microsoft Teams, but in summary, it will be best if we could create a team upon on existing site, so that the "Files" and "Notes" tabs would directly reference the existing document library and OneNote in SharePoint. It does not make sense to have two separate sites: one for all the usual SharePoint stuff, and another just for Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Currently this is not possible. New SharePoint site will default  be created when you create new team.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is still in the backlog. For more details, please refer to [Microsoft Teams UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16930312-create-team-from-existing-sharepoint-site-and-oth)

Thanks